# Is it possible merge the main branch (with custom code) with the flutterflow branch?

Tags: flutter

(Following that guide: [Manage Custom Code In GitHub](https://docs.flutterflow.io/customizing-your-app/manage-custom-code-in-github)
) it is posible (after from deploy application) merge the main branch with the flutter flow branch to continue building app based in the last changes deployed?

my question is summarized in this diagram edited from flutterflow original.[image]

If possible, could you explain to me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

FlutterFlow pushes changes to GitHub. It can't pull it back.
You can merge your `main` branch to `flutterflow` branch using git. But I am not sure how FlutterFlow manages conflicts in `flutterflow` branch. Also it is not useful because FlutterFlow will not be pulling those changes to their dashboard. It is oneway flow.

They suggest to push changes to GitHub and manage all custom code there. So create a branch from `main` and merge `flutterflow` with new changes. Test the changes and merge it back to main for release.